# Odes15 sub plotting, differential equations

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, ode, differential-equations, subplot

So I have three differential equations relating to diabetes, I have to plot the 2 out of the three, them being G and I in a subplot. For some reason when I attempt to run it the command window prints out: "Not enough input arguments"  This is the criteria for it:

```
function dx = problem1(t,x)     
    P1 = 0.028735 ;
    P2 = 0.028344 ;
    P3 = 5.035 * 10^(-5) ;
    Vi = 12 ;
    n = 5/54 ;
    D_t = 3*exp(-0.05*t) ;
    U_t = 3 ;
    Gb = 4.5;
    Xb = 15;
    Ib = 15;

    G = x(1);
    X = x(2);
    I = x(3);

    dx = zeros(3,1);
    dx(1) = -P1*(G-Gb) - (X-Xb)*G + D_t ;
    dx(2) = -P2*(X-Xb) + P3*(I-Ib) ;
    dx(3) = -n*I + U_t/Vi ;

    [T,X] = ode15s(@problem1,[0 60*24],[4.5 15 15]) ;

subplot(3,1,1);
plot(T,X(:,1)); % Plot G
subplot(3,1,2); % Second subplot
plot(T,X(:,2)); % Plot I
```

Comment: What is the final output you are getting?

Comment: Well it is telling me that "Not enough input arguments".

Comment: Matlab error messages are very helpful. What is the complete message and on what line does it occur?

Comment: The full error message is : Error using problem1 (line 7)
Not enough input arguments.

Comment: Don't really know where to go from that. I already attempted looking into and following the MATLAB website's ode15s examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is thrown when you run the function and MATLAB attempts to evaluate `D_t = 3*exp(-0.05*t);`.  Since no value of `t` was given, MATLAB throws an error saying that the up-to-that-point unused `t` variable must be specified.

The main problem with the code is in the function's design.  Namely, `ode15s` needs a function that accepts a `t` and an `x` and returns `dx`; however, as it is currently laid out, the call to `ode15s` is embedded within `problem1` which itself requires a `t` and `x`.  It is a chicken-or-egg problem.

**All of the input is correct** aside from this design problem and can easily be corrected using a separate function for the ODE's definition:

```
function problem1

    [T,X] = ode15s(@ODE,[0 60*24],[4.5 15 15]) ;  
    subplot(3,1,1);
    plot(T,X(:,1)); % Plot G
    subplot(3,1,2); % Second subplot
    plot(T,X(:,2)); % Plot I

end

function dx = ODE(t,x)
    P1 = 0.028735 ;
    P2 = 0.028344 ;
    P3 = 5.035 * 10^(-5) ;
    Vi = 12 ;
    n = 5/54 ;
    D_t = 3*exp(-0.05*t) ;
    U_t = 3 ;
    Gb = 4.5;
    Xb = 15;
    Ib = 15;

    G = x(1);
    X = x(2);
    I = x(3);

    dx = zeros(3,1);
    dx(1) = -P1*(G-Gb) - (X-Xb)*G + D_t ;
    dx(2) = -P2*(X-Xb) + P3*(I-Ib) ;
    dx(3) = -n*I + U_t/Vi ;
end
```

Notes:

- The first line `function problem1` is short-hand for `function [] = problem1()`.  I prefer the latter form myself, but I'm in the minority.
- The function handle passed to `ode15s` `@ODE` is short-hand for `@(t,x) ODE(t,x)`.  I prefer the latter form myself, but it is no less or more valid as long as you are not [parametrizing functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html?refresh=true).
- You can also use a nested function and give the `problem1` function access to the model constants, but I opted for a separate function here.

Comment: Thank You!!! I know this is right since I took a glimpse of the solution when the professor showed us!!!